# How to setup custom domain DNS for azure?

Tags: azure, dns

I am trying to setup my domain to azure website. but it only works for www.sagheer.me not for sagheer.me

MY DNS Setting is:

> CNAME : www.sagheer.me - sagheer.azurewebsites.net
>   A     : sagheer.me     - 168.62.48.183

if open sagheer.me it says 404 directory not found.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the A record to point to azure websites, you have to also create a CNAME to verify your domain.

For your case the CNAME record will be:

```
CNAME: awverify.www.sagheer.me - awverify.sagheer.azurewebsites.net
```

For full details, you can [see here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/#bkmk_configurearecord).

Comment: not worked for me. Azure keep saying DNS Records not found. My domain registrar is ENOM

Comment: Did you wait long enough for the changes to propagate.  I was able to pull up both www.sagheer.me and sagheer.me.  Seems to be working now?

Comment: No, now i am hosting it on my linux server. For azure i waited 24 hours. It didn't work.

Comment: OK i have added cnames back again and i will try again later on azure if it work at least of www